# Speech not getting transcripted while using Agora and Vosk

Tags: android, kotlin, agora.io, vosk

I am using Agora SDK to voice call and I want speech transcription while in the call so I have used Vosk SDK to transcript my speech

Here I am facing one issue that simultaneously not both SDKs are working either Agora Voice call can work or Vosk

The issue here is at a time only one AudioRecorder can get access to the recording

But I want to like both can work together so that I can achieve speech to text and voice calling feature at the same time

Is there any workaround to get resolve this?

Comment: You can get the audio recording from vosk and feed to the Agora SDK.

Comment: @NanaGhartey i have done the same but this case audio contains noise as by using custom audio source to feed in Agora SDK it does not cancel noise and Echo while in call